# Why doesn't this Comparator segregate odd and even numbers correcly

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

Below is my attempt (failed and successful) for segregating odd and even numbers in an array. The expected output is to have all the even numbers before the odd numbers in the array. So, a valid output is

```
2 4 6 8 10 9 7 5 3 1
```

The one in comments is the version that does not work, and the other version works.

In the failed version, I am wondering why it does not work. What I am doing is, if the first number is odd, and the second is even, I swap it. In all other cases, I don't do any swapping, which is okay, since no swapping is required if both numbers are even, or both numbers are odd, or if already the even number comes before the odd, in which case, it is already maintaining the pattern of the expected output.

```
public void evenOddComparator()
    {
        Integer[] a = {4,3,1,2,5,6,8,9,7,10};
//        Integer[] a = {3,4};

        Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>()
            {
//                @Override
//                public int compare(Integer a1, Integer a2)
//                {
//                    if( ((a1%2) == 1) && ((a2%2) == 0))
//                        return 1;
//                    return 0;
//                }

                final int BEFORE = -1;
                final int EQUAL = 0;
                final int AFTER = 1;

                @Override
                public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                    if (o1 % 2 == 0 && o2 % 2 != 0) {
                        return BEFORE;
                    } else if (o1 % 2 != 0 && o2 % 2 == 0) {
                        return AFTER;
                    } else if (o1 % 2 == 0 && o2 % 2 == 0) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    } else if (o1 % 2 != 0 && o2 % 2 != 0) {
                        return o2.compareTo(o1);
                    }

                    return EQUAL;
                }
            });
        print(a);   
    }
```

Can you help me understand why the commented out logic is not working as expected?

Comment: The return value of `compare` isn't "do I swap or not". It indicates *which, if either, of the arguments is "greater" in terms of this comparator's ordering*. Your failed comparator does not return what it's supposed to return.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks. But what do -1, 1 and 0, signify in that case?

Comment: They signify whether the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second, by the standards of the ordering the comparator implements.

Comment: @user121, thanks, but I sill don't understand why my commented out implementation fails. The way it is implemented, if the first argument is odd, and the second is even, it returns 1, implying that the first argument is greater than the second, and so needs swapping, since Arrays.sort ideally, tries to sort elements in ascending sorted order. In all other cases, it just returns back 0, saying that, both elements are equal, and so, the sorting logic can think it's getting closer to the "sorted" output.

Comment: If `a1` is even and `a2` is odd, the elements are **not equal** by the ordering you need to implement. `a1` is smaller. The sorting algorithm is **not** asking your comparator whether to swap these numbers. The sorting algorithm may not even have a concept of "swap" at all. It's certainly not a bubblesort or anything like that.

Comment: You are imagining that the sorting algorithm uses your comparator by going `if (comparator.compare(x, y) == 1) {swap x and y}`. It doesn't do that. The sorting algorithm is most likely a [highly-tuned adaptive mergesort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) based on [the algorithm Tim Peters wrote for Python](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt). It uses your comparator in much more complex ways.

Comment: @user2357112, that is EXACTLY how I am thinking, glad you got through to me. But not glad that, if that's not right, then what is. The way, I look at it, i have modeled my segregation problem to a sorting one, and defined what "greater" is. It would still make sense to me, if we returned original numbers, and not -1,0,1 flags. If it's not for swapping, then, what is the purpose of these flags? Can you try explaining that to me. Maybe, that would clear it up for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138876/discussion-between-user121-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem with your commented code is that you are breaking an expected consistency condition of all implementation of comparisons:

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T- but the same language is in `Comparator`. (There are two other similar conditions in that section which you should also read and understand).

In your case 3 compare 2 = 1 and 2 compare 3 = 0. This makes your implementation break an assumed precondition of all the sorting algorithms in Java hence it doesn't work.

The reason this is important is that otherwise the final order would depend on which elements happened to form each side of a comparison. If the algorithm happened to compare 2 to 3 rather than 3 to 2 then you would end with a different order. The documentation insists that you return exactly the negative result by swapping the sides so that all implementations can be arbitrary about which elements form the first and second arguments in the comparison. This allows efficiency (and, as an aside, matches the mathematical definition of a comparison).

I also note that in your question you are implying that implementing a comparison is designed to denote what to swap and what not to swap in a sorting operation. That's not true at all. There are many different sorting algorithms and many of them don't swap anything - they copy or split and rejoin or use many other techniques. Or the comparison could be finding the largest or smallest element.

So when you define a comparison you are not indicating what to swap; rather you are defining what is smaller and what is larger (within this comparison) and leaving the details of how it's used to the algorithm you are calling. You should never assume that you know how that algorithm works (especially as it will change from JVM to JVM and version to version). Just follow the conditions in the documentation and it will be guaranteed to work irrespective of how the algorithms change.

As an aside, you can achieve your result with the single statement:

```
sort(a, comparingInt(n -> floorMod(n, 2));
```

This just converts each number to a 0 or 1 depending on whether it is even or odd and then compares those instead. It uses `Math.floorMod` so that it can handle negative numbers correctly (which your implementation doesn't).

Comment: that does make sense, but why does it treat and assume 3 compare 2 and 2 compare 2 to give the same output. The flags -1, and +1 clearly state that the firs argument is lower than the second, and vice versa

Comment: No not the same output: one must be the negative of the other for consistency reasons.

Comment: I've put a further note about why it's important in the answer.

Comment: But that is exactly what my commented out code does. 3 compare 2 would return 1, and 2 compare 3 would return 0(I could change that to -1 which would makes it the negative of the other). In fact, I changed return 0 to return -1, and it works as expected

Comment: If you just change 0 to -1 you are now saying that 2 compare 2 = -1 which makes no sense

Comment: but in terms of the output, it's okay, because, from what I've been observing, +1 causes elements to swap, whereas 0 as well as -1 does not swap elements, and they cling on to their place.

Comment: I don't know how to make it any clearer for you than the answer I've given. What you are observing is wrong. +1 does not always 'cause elements to swap'. Even if it works here it will cause issues if you don't follow the documentation. Trust me on this one :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138877/discussion-between-user121-and-sprinter).

Comment: I understand that we basically, implement a comparator, make it return either of -1/1/0. But, finally it has to aid, the underlying algorithm, which is Arrays.sort? My question is, when Arrays.sort sees a +1, -1 or 1, what does it do? I would've thought it decides whether to swap or no, but as you said, that is not right thinking. Thanks.

Comment: Nice explanation, +1. Note that `n -> n % 2` fails for negative numbers, though I understand this was derived from the OP's example code and input, which has no negative numbers. I usually prefer `n -> n & 1` but for some reason bitwise operators often seem to confuse people.

Comment: @StuartMarks good point on negatives: hadn't thought of that. Will change to `floorMod`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare functions are used for determining which number is larger. You have to make any odd number evaluate as larger.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = {4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 10};
//        Integer[] a = {3,4};

        Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                if (o1%2 == o2%2) {
                    // Both numbers are odd or both numbers are even
                    return 0;
                }
                // One is odd, the other one is even
                if (o1%2 == 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            }
        });
        for(int x:a) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. So technically, although we are not "sorting", we use the underlying Sorting logic, and trick it to believe that even coming first,in this case, is the definition of "lesser". Please confirm if this is right

Comment: @user121: You *are* sorting.

Comment: @user121, hmm, sorry, but where am I sorting. I am only trying to segregate odd from even.

Comment: @user121 that is correct. Arrays.sort goes through an array comparing all the elements to determine and order for them. By default this normally means something like "a>b" but we can implement any logic we want. In my example it sorts it so any odd number is greater than any even number

Comment: @user121: You call `Arrays.sort`. It's right there in the name. You don't think of it as sorting, but you really need to start thinking of it that way.

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert, thanks so much. This clears up a lot of things. But, I am still blocked on understanding why my commented out implementation does not work. If odd comes before even, I want it to feel that the first number is greater, and so pass 1 for swapping. In all other cases, I'm okay with it feeling that nothing needs to be done, so I make it believe that the first argument is smaller than the second (expected output order for Arrays.sort by returning 0) implying you're good, don't do anything

Comment: @user121: Among the many unfounded assumptions you're making about how `Arrays.sort` uses your comparator, why are you assuming that the first argument to `compare` will always be left of the second argument in the array?

Comment: @user121 It's because your comparator is getting confused. It should be consistent when comparing two entities. Your comparator would evaluate compare(5,6) differently than compare(6,5)

Comment: Simpler body of the comparison would be `o1 % 2 - o2 % 2`.

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert, Brian, if I replace the return 0 in my commented out code, with return -1, it not only gives me the correct answer, but also pretty much resembles your code above. The only difference that would still remain is that if both o1 and o2 are odd, or both even, it would still return -1, whereas you return 0. So, isn't just replacing the return 0 with return -1 sufficient? in what case, would this be insufficient/confuse the comparator?

Comment: @user121 Arrays.sort processes the collection left to right so using the comparator in this instance works but it is not good practice